# What are these javascript methods

Tags: javascript, methods, xmldom

Looking through some open source javascript library and I've come across some single character methods a few times:

```
myVar.c('foo').t('bar');
```

myVar refers to an XML DOM element. So what are c() and t()? I don't see any reference to such methods in the API: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_element.asp

Comment: They are plugin method..

Comment: That depends on the library. Without linking the file where you found them, we hardly can help you.

Comment: @C-linkNepal: What does that mean?

Comment: My mistake. Looking into it further I realized that myVar is actually a wrapper class around the XML DOM element, and it has some convenience methods c() and t().

Answer (score 2):

There is one remote possibility. When javascript is minified single letters are used to reduce function names. Your example above may be a minified version **[file].min.js** and therefore function names are obfuscated.

Comment: No, minification rarely changes property names. Only case I know of is with Google's Closure Compiler in Advanced Mode when the annotations and usages allow it.